# find the dimension of the given space?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $W_1$ be the real vector space  of all $5 \times 2$ matrices of  such that the sum  the sum of   the  entries  in each row   is  $0 $. let $W_2$be the real vector space of all $5 \times 2$ matrices  such that the   sum  of the entries  in each  column is zero .find the   dimension of the space  $W _1 \cap W_2$

my attempts :$\max[0,\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)- 5] \le \dim(W_1 ∩ W_2) \le \min[ \dim(W_1) ,\dim (W_2),]$

so $\dim(W_1 ∩ W_2) = 2$

Am i right ?

Comment: You are not. I suppose that You calculate $\dim(W_1)$ and $\dim(W_2)$ in a wrong way. $\dim(W_2)$ is much larger than $2$.

Comment: I think the answer is 4. A row vector sums to 0 means it must have dimension 4. And since the columns sum to 0 once the first row is fixed the next row is negative of the first row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements of $W_1 \cap W_2$ satisfy the condition that the sum of each row and each column is $0$.

Hence the first row completely determines the next row and the first $4$ entries of the first row would determine the $5$ element, hence the dimension is $4$.

Comment: thanks Siong THye